# Reasons for strain gauge drift

Tags: wheatstone-bridge

I'm testing a load cell where the result drifts over time.

By weighing it down with a known weight over night, the result crept up by 10% in 18 hours. It's a completely linear increase, with consistent variations due to noise.

I'm using a HBM QuantumX MX840B and two pairs of strain gauges that form a full bridge. The cable has been perfectly still during the test. The strain gauges are 120 ohm and it's been set at a 5V exitation voltage. The load cell is of stainless steel and is quite massive, so I would assume heat dissipation shouldn't be too big of an issue, but I don't know.

Temperature is reasonably stable (it's indoor) and the full wheatstrone bridge would compensate for change, something we also tested with a heat gun.

I'll re-mount the strain gauges on the load cell and see if it gets better, but I'm not sure as to why it drifts, and especially in such a linear way, and advice would be helpful.

Edit: This is what I'm going to do in order to re-mount it properly, please give me input as to where your experience differs from this.

Physical installation of strain gauge:

- Remove all strain gauges
- Clean with isopropanol
- Prepare the area with rough grinder if need be
- Sand down to 320 grit with electric sander or grinder flappy disks
- Slightly roughen the texture with a courser paper to increase adhesion
- Clean with isopropanol again Put a small amount of HBM Z70 cyanoacrylate glue
- Push the strain gauge down with my thumb Cover with suitable material (silicone or similar)

**Results from load cell overnight testing:**

This is from testing the first cell over night, it dips considerably.
[image: Initial test, first load cell]

This is from the second cell, it has a much smaller variation. It makes a huge dip in the morning, something we have seen before. This is because the test lab has eight huge halogen lamps in the ceiling that draws a big current when starting, I'm certain those affect the results. What is concerning is that it does not recover back to it's previous state.

[image: Latest test, second load cell]

Comment: 208 mW may not seem like much but unless the gauges are temperature compensated then you will get errors. Show the data for the gauges used.

Comment: Well that's the grand total, but divided over 4 separate strain gauges in order to form a full bridge. This is designed to have two axial strain gauges, and two strain gauges normal to the axial strain, as to get zero strain and act as a temperature/cable compensation, I presume. I didn't design the thing myself. I don't have the data on this computer, but sufficient to say, it weighed down with 1520kg yesterday afternoon, and this morning it was increased to 1670.

Comment: You presume it acts as temperature compensation? Rule out the possibility that there is insufficient compensation.

Comment: It physically does act as a temperature compensation. The strain is determined by a formula that adds two of the gauges and subtracts two, and they are all glued physically to the same material. As I decribed in the original post, we also used a heat gun on the load cell in order to control for the effect of sudden temperature changes, for which there were none.  This is of course external temperature variations, I assume overheating the gauges itself will cause problems.

Comment: it also might be your ADC... I never figured it out, but I had done some work with HX711 boards,  and they exhibited behavior like you describe under ostensibly static loading.

Comment: what is the temperature coefficient of the used steel and strain gauge? Did you use the same coeff?

Comment: @Marko that’s a good question, but wouldn’t such a discrepancy only affect the linear accuracy of the measurement, rather than make it drift while at a constant load? As it happens I think these old cells are simply calibrated with a tension machine and given a linear scale based on the actual measurements.

Comment: @vicatu the hx711 has a quite good adc, but afaik it doesn’t support six wire connections, so it has quite a lot of potential to give you bad readings due to external factors. Otherwise I’d use it, the equipment we are using unfortunately costs a thousand times more.

Comment: Is the strain gauge and all its electronics in a temperature-compensated environment? If not, then all the other suggestions are moot.

Comment: @MikeWaters that's not really possible. However the electronics are in a closed cabinet which keeps a somewhat stable temperature, and the load cells themselves are submerged in the sea, which also keeps a constant temperature. Six-wired full bridges seem to not be affected much by temperature variations in the lab either. An uncompensated gauge flcutuated wildly just by the warmth of a hand in proximity of it.

Answer (score 2):

Mounting strain gauges is an art. Your long term variation seems to me that the gauges are mounted in a way that the adhesive is not keeping them in the same position over an extended period of time. At least this is what I would consider after making sure to rule out temperature and voltage variations.

Comment: I agree that seems to be the most likely point, but I'd like to go through any sort of potential issue that could cause this problem.

 What I'm going to do is the following:
Remove all strain gauges
Clean with isopropanol
Prepare the area with rough grinder if need be
Sand down to 320 grit with electric sander or grinder flappy disks
Slightly roughen the texture with a courser paper to increase adhesion
Clean with isopropanol again
Put a small amount of HBM Z70 cyanoacrylate glue
Push the strain gauge down with my thumb
Cover with suitable material (silicone or similar)

Comment: The easiest thing here is to repeat the tests multiple times. Adhesive creep under the strain gauges is most likely to occur with the tension direction and not in the compression direction....but who knows. I would repeat long term tests alternately with load and no load and cycle three or four time to see if some stability appears or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, also with different load cells, in order to provide some consistent results. Right now I'm using a forklift, lifting the load cell and hanging a giant swivel under it as weight, with the forks being propped up by a beam in order to resist the creep of the hydraulic cylinder of the fork lifter. So I can only do one at a time, so this will take some weeks (and the fork lift).

Comment: Are you applying adhesive at the joint flap and then letting the surface tension wick it into something approximating a monolayer?

Comment: @ScottSeidman do you mean where the solder pad is? I haven't done it personally so many times, I think I recall taping the soldering pad to the material, then applying glue on the surface and pushing down gently but firm with my thumb for about 5-10 seconds. Since I've never done any kind of courses, having that touch as Michael mentioned.. I don't have it and I'm not sure how little is too little when it comes to the glue. But I understand it must be a very thin layer.

Comment: I mean at the junction of the gauge and the substrate (i.e., material it's mounted on), as in figure 5-1 in https://assets.omega.com/manuals/M1270.pdf  -- The proper application is a bead of thin glue at that junction.  As the "flap" is lowered, the glue gets wicked to cover the whole glue surface.  Follow with pressure from your thumb, sliding over the gauge as it gets lowered.  You want a uniform layer.

Comment: Can you not place the load cells in series and observe them for any common drift errors.  Does the drift always occur in the same loading direction? If so then adhesive creep or unexpected plastic deformation of substrate is indicated.

Comment: @scott thanks, that was a very to-the-point manual. I will make sure to do it like that.

Comment: @KalleMP you mean hang them after each other? I haven’t really thought of that. I tried again with a new cable, and on my most recent test, the strain actually decreased in an inverse parabolic shape for some hours before it gradually started to creep up again quite linearly over night. I am running a new test over the course of the weekend to see if it just keeps going.

Comment: @SirVegardG Yes, hang one above the other with a suitable static load below.  The top one will read higher but if you unload the string during your testing each one should have an identical step change.  If you can record (even by hand) the changes and they are not consistent you can eliminate many environmental causes (temperature, excitation supply (if common), ageing) if you can include a calibrated/lab-grade gauge in the string you can monitor the difference and infer errors in the test environment (absorption or loss of humidity by your dummy load). ....

Comment: @SirVegardG  ...   Fixing the gauge elements is a trained skill set and it may pay to have a consultant do the placement for one of your test units in the string.  Use the gauge supplier specified adhesive until you have reproducible results. Also approach an alternate vendor for samples of compatible elements so that you can rule out bad quality or Monday batch.  Check for unlikely event that the potting compound is of adequate quality and dryness.  Double check condition of wires, all leads MUST be of same type until you know how to economise where possible.

Comment: @KalleMP we'll try that tonight, looking fwd to the test. Updated my first post with resutls from weekend's testing. Do you have any experience with shielding affecting results of strain gauges? We're using it outside, in an environment with virtually no electromagnetic noise, however the cables are close to metal. The problem is that the connectors I ordered, I only ordered 6 pin, and they have a plastic housing. Meaning that I can't use the shielding, made a bit of a mistake there.

Comment: @SirVegardG You could connect the shield to the lowest potential excitation pin on both sides on the connector only and leave it unconnected elsewhere, not ideal but still better than nothing against electrostatic noise.  The fuzz on your curves is 'noise' induced but looks like LSB ADC jitter of little concern, the steps are a concern and may be excitation powersupply failings but the uncorrelated drift is still unexplained.

Comment: KalleMP, I'll try that and see if it affects my readings. I ordered some more 7-pin connectors  from the supplier just so I'm able to make sure, at least in the beginning. But it would be nice to use those 50pcs of connectors with 6 pin.

Answer (score 0):

Might be heating due to current, though the full bridge should mostly null that out.  Could be creep. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creep_(deformation).  Could be drift of your excitation voltage.

Comment: Well it does say that material creep occurs at 35% of the melting temperature of the material, which for ANSI316 SS would be rather high. When these things are in production they are actually under water, so cooled down by seawater, but still giving us loads of problems.

Comment: Could be creep in the bond, in addition to the substrate.

Comment: Also see https://www.strainblog.com/content/introduction-gage-creep

Comment: Sorry, English isn't my first language, is the substrate the surface of the measured material? Yes, the bond might be the problem, I'm not sure how much glue they used or which kind. As far as I've learned, cyanoacrylate is the go-to adhesive for strain gauges in normal temperatures, but some are much more thin-flowing than others. I know we've had a goopy kind before, which might cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I‘d suspect the type of glue. We use M-Bond 610, which is a special two-component hot glue. This also needs conditioning and neutralizing with the proper chemicals, after sanding just the right way. Applying strain gauges really is an art and requires careful process design and loads of know-how. If you need professional help, contact me. The company I work at specialises in one-off and custom designed load cells for new installations and/or replacement of unobtainable parts. We would be happy to help!

Edit: We can laser-weld for IP68 rating as well.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a website? We've nailed the process down a lot better thanks to this thread. It's still a lot to learn though, I guess experience helps.